# How to copy information from previous rows into a blank row in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to create a new table of sample information based on a previous experiment. We are trying to add two new conditions to the samples that were previously run with three conditions. My table currently looks like this:

```
    Sample_ID  dx gender condition tube_no
    AB001       1     2          1      1A
    AB001       1     2          2      1B
    AB001       1     2          3      1C
    NA         NA    NA         NA      NA
    NA         NA    NA         NA      NA
    AB002       2     1          1      2A
    ...
```

And it repeats this way for approximately 560 samples. So, I have been able to import all of the sample information and have created two empty lines for the next two conditions to go into, but the problem is I basically need to copy the information in the first three rows while changing the information in the last two rows. The output should look like this:

```
    Sample_ID dx gender condition tube_no
    AB001       1     2          1      1A
    AB001       1     2          2      1B
    AB001       1     2          3      1C
    AB001       1     2          4      1D
    AB001       1     2          5      1E
    AB002       2     1          1      2A
    ...
```

Does anyone know of a good way to partially copy information from previous table rows into new table rows? I appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can first `fill` the first 3 columns, then grouped by 'Sample_ID' `mutate` the 'condition' as the sequence of rows (`row_number()`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate_at(vars(Sample_ID, dx, gender), na_if, y = "") %>%
   fill(Sample_ID,  dx, gender) %>%
    group_by(Sample_ID) %>%
    mutate(condition = row_number())
```

---

If the original object is a `data.table`, an option is to combine with `na.locf0` from `zoo`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <-  c("Sample_ID",  "dx", "gender")
setDT(df1)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, na.locf0), .SDcols = nm1
      ][, condition := seq_len(.N), .(Sample_ID)]
```

Comment: I think OP is using data.table.

Comment: Won't setting the 'condition' to row numbers cause them to just list as 1-560? I would need them to repeat every 5 rows from 1-5.

Comment: @ktmcb. In the example showed, the `AB001` frequency is 3  + 2 NA, so i considered it as 5 rows.  As we do the `group_by(Sample_ID)`, the row_number would start again on each group i.e. 1:5, 1:5, ..

Comment: I just tried the first block of code, it filled in the condition column like this: `1 2 3 1 2 1 2 3 3 4 1 2 3 5 6 ...etc` So it just filled in the empty columns in order instead of repeating them 1-5.

Comment: @ktmcb. If it needs to be not based on 'SampleID', the condition needs to be changed

Comment: Sorry, should have added- it looks like the `fill(Sample_ID, dx, gender)` line didn't work, all of the spots in the extra rows are still blank, except condition

Comment: @ktmcb Here, I am assuming that `NA` is not "NA"

Comment: Ah, very sorry, I didn't know there was a difference. The extra rows are blank, they do not have NA in them, I just used that in the example as a placeholder.

Comment: @ktmcb In that case, it needss to be changed to `NA` i.e. `df1 %>% mutate_at(vars(Sample_ID,  dx, gender), na_if, "") %>% fill(Sample_ID,  dx, gender) %>%`